# Regex Capture Middle Value

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I would like to ask for your help...

I have this string where I have to get the **4.75**. I've tried many regex expression but I could not get it to work and been through browsing lots of examples as well.

[Regexr Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsdCQ.png)

```
Loan Amount Interest Rate

$336,550 4.75 %
```

So far, below is my current expression

```
1. (?<=Interest Rate\s*\n*)([^\s]+).+(?=%)
```

I'm getting the **$336,550 4.75**

```
2. ([^\s]+).(?=%)
```

Resulted into multiple output. In my entire text, which I can't share, there are also other data that is in %.

I am only after the 4.75. I know I can just select the first match via code (i guess) but for now it is not an option.

Thanks in advance!

I've tried different regex expression

Answer (score 0):

You just need to extract "4.75 %" ?
Try this:

```
(?<=Interest Rate\n\n\$\d{3},\d{3}\s)(\d{1,5}\.\d{1,5}\s%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your regex with variable length patterns inside lookbehind works, you can use the following .NET compliant regex:

```
(?<=Interest Rate\s+\S+\s+)(\S+)(?=\s*%)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fgfpxw/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=Interest Rate\s+\S+\s+)` - a positive lookbehind that requires `Interest Rate`, one or more whitespaces, one or more non-whitespaces and again one or more whitespaces immediately to the left of the current location
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?=\s*%)` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more whitespaces and then a `%` char immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: @kcodes Rather than saying thank you which is off-topic, please follow the SO guidelines as per asking and getting answers.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Please try this.

```
[0-9]+.[0-9]+
```